# Best practice labeling (unreferenced) equations in latex

Tags: equations, labels

when writing texts where there is a lot of math, should I label all equations with a number or is it more appropiate to only number the equations that I refer to in the text? Sometimes I get into situations such as
[image: Sample "Derivation" - which equations should be labeled?]

I know that it could be a good idea to rewrite all steps with "Then using X we rewrite equation 2 as ...", but suppose I want to leave the text as it is, which equations are appropiate to enumerate? I've seen some athours that enumerate most equations, and others that barely enumerate any.

I know that the question is a bit vauge, but essentially I wonder if someone has some general advice on enumerating equations? I haven't been able to find any references about it elsewhere. I'm a bit unsure if I should've asked this question in some other forum, but I felt like this is more of a Latex-convention question.

Thank in advance

Comment: Sorry but this is an opinion-based matter. The packages `mathtools` and `autonum` provide ways of showing only referenced questions: that's the TeX part. But the question whether to do this or not is a merely stylistic choice.

Comment: @campa Yes, I understand that it is a matter of preference, I just wanted to hear why someone would choose one layout over another.

Comment: I think the rationale for numbering *everything* is for ease of reference by others. It seems to be a common practice in many engineering journals. In mathematics journals, on the other hand, it is common practice to just number the equations you yourself need to reference. (I assume exceptions can be found on both sides of this issue.)

Comment: @campa I wouldn't call the choice *merely stylistic*. It is more a question of the expected benefits or not of having all those equation numbers. Which in turn depends on who will be reading the document and how will they use it. See my comment above.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I fully agree with your comments. Maybe the word "stylistic" was a poor lexical choice on my side: what I meant is simply that this is no TeX question.